# total_results of plugin nested within exp:query

Tags: plugin, query, count

I'm using the exp:query module along with a nested custom plugin that I've created. I need to get the count and total_results of the nested plugin but it's returning the count and total_results of the exp:query, which wraps around the plugin tags. If I move the custom plugin outside of the exp:query (for testing), it returns the plugin's count.

Is it possible to return the count and total_results of a plugin nested within an exp:query? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways you can do that.

1) Use `parse="inward"` parameter on your custom plugin code. (There is very few possibility of this to working.)

2) Move your nested custom plugin code into any other file and call it via `{embed='template_group/template'}` under your query loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, Mufi.

parse="inward" didn't work and using embed would be too much overhead (lots of items pulled using exp:query so each item would've needed its own embed.)

I ended up finding a workaround but am still hoping there's a way to make this possible.